# What data types can be exported as attributes when exporting to `graphml` with `networkx`?

Tags: python, xml, numpy, networkx, graphml

I have a `networkx` graph with some `list` and `dict` attributes that the function `nx.write_graphml` doesn't accept as valid type for the export. I couldn't find a function that would automatically ignore those attributes so I decided to create one myself.

I know that `int`, `float` and `string` are accepted, but I don't know if there are others and, if so, which ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graphml` format follows `XML` structure and according to the [docs](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/graphml-format/), the following data types are accepted:

> Each attribute title is defined in a key element with an identifier, a name, a title, edge or node, and the type of data. The supported data types:
>
> - boolean
> - int
> - long
> - float
> - double
> - string

If the lists are not too long, then one suggestion is to create numbered attributes (e.g. `colour_1`, `colour_2`). Similarly, for dictionaries. This is not convenient, but these are `graphml` constraints.

Also, if you do not intend to use the `list` or `dict` in Gephi, but want to preserve them for later use, then one option is to convert them to a string representation using something like [`json.dumps`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824345/10693596).

Update: when writing the data, `networkx` will try to convert the data types to the allowed representations. For example, the list of `numpy`-specific conversions can be found [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/36d446bae7059d9a6b2db742f3b75457f89db032/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py#L406-L431).

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped a lot in particular the idea of converting them to string instead of deleting them

you cited what graphml can store i think it is safe to say that int bool string and float class won't raise any error but does that mean others will for example i think numpy has his own class for long integer. will it raise an error or will it be accepted. I'm gone figure out

Comment: Great, it seems that [numpy won't work either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70521336/10693596), but it could be converted into a list (of it's referring to a single value, then just to an int or a float)...

Comment: i just tested i actually work with numpy
`g = nx.Graph()
i = np.double(3)
type(i)
g.add_node(1, id=i)
nx.write_graphml(g, "g.graphml")` doesn't raise any error. Therefore there is other defined class tthat works with this writer

Comment: Ah, I think in this case it works because it's just a single number, but if this was an array, `networkx` would complain.

Comment: The post you cited was one where he wanted to have a `numpy.ndarray` which is not compatible as it is with the specification of the graphml while i wanted to look at the numpy class that are theoretically compatible with gephy but are not python built-in representations of the graphml supported data types

Comment: I totally agree with you but it means that i can't just test if it is one of the four built-in class. I need another test to see if it will be or not accepted by the writer

Comment: [This list of `numpy`-related handling in `networkx`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/36d446bae7059d9a6b2db742f3b75457f89db032/networkx/readwrite/graphml.py#L406-L431) might be useful. I'll update the answer with this also.

Comment: I think you actually found the entire list of types alowed which seems to be only built-in and all their cousins in numpy. I will validate your answer once you've changed it